# Sticky CSS Footer

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me make the original code from HTML5 Boilerplate Initializser, have the footer stick to the bottom of the browser, I've tried all manor of codes from web examples but unfortunately I think as usual the boiler plates predefined CSS is affecting the positioning and "sticking" of the footer.

Heres my CSS:

```
 /* =============================================================================
   HTML5 Boilerplate CSS: h5bp.com/css
   ========================================================================== */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section { display: block; }
audio, canvas, video { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }
audio:not([controls]) { display: none; }
[hidden] { display: none; }

html { font-size: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; height: 100%;}
html, button, input, select, textarea { font-family: sans-serif; color: #222; }
body { margin: 0; font-size: 0.9em; line-height: 1.4; height: 100%;}

::-moz-selection { background: #fe57a1; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background: #fe57a1; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }

a { color: #00e; }
a:visited { color: #551a8b; }
a:hover { color: #06e; }
a:focus { outline: thin dotted; }
a:hover, a:active { outline: 0; }

abbr[title] { border-bottom: 1px dotted; }
b, strong { font-weight: bold; }
blockquote { margin: 1em 40px; }
dfn { font-style: italic; }
hr { display: block; height: 1px; border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 1em 0; padding: 0; }
ins { background: #ff9; color: #000; text-decoration: none; }
mark { background: #ff0; color: #000; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; }
pre, code, kbd, samp { font-family: monospace, serif; _font-family: 'courier new', monospace; font-size: 0.9em; }
pre { white-space: pre; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
q { quotes: none; }
q:before, q:after { content: ""; content: none; }
small { font-size: 85%; }

sub, sup { font-size: 75%; line-height: 0; position: relative; vertical-align: baseline; }
sup { top: -0.5em; }
sub { bottom: -0.25em; }

ul, ol { margin: 1em 0; padding: 0 0 0 40px; }
dd { margin: 0 0 0 40px; }
nav ul, nav ol { list-style: none; list-style-image: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

img { border: 0; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; vertical-align: middle; }

svg:not(:root) { overflow: hidden; }

figure { margin: 0; }

form { margin: 0; }
fieldset { border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
label { cursor: pointer; }
legend { border: 0; *margin-left: -7px; padding: 0; white-space: normal; }
button, input, select, textarea { font-size: 100%; margin: 0; vertical-align: baseline; *vertical-align: middle; }
button, input { line-height: normal; }
button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] { cursor: pointer; -webkit-appearance: button; *overflow: visible; }
button[disabled], input[disabled] { cursor: default; }
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; *width: 13px; *height: 13px; }
input[type="search"] { -webkit-appearance: textfield; -moz-box-sizing: content-box; -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; box-sizing: content-box; }
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration, input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button { -webkit-appearance: none; }
button::-moz-focus-inner, input::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; padding: 0; }
textarea { overflow: auto; vertical-align: top; resize: vertical; }
input:valid, textarea:valid {  }
input:invalid, textarea:invalid { background-color: #f0dddd; }

table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
td { vertical-align: top; }

.chromeframe { margin: 0.2em 0; background: #ccc; color: black; padding: 0.2em 0; }


/* ===== Initializr Styles =====================================================
   Author: Jonathan Verrecchia - verekia.com/initializr/responsive-tfont-sizeplate
   ========================================================================== */

body{ font:16px/26px Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial; }

.wrapper{
    width:90%;
    margin:0 5%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* ===================
    ALL: Blue Theme 
   =================== */

#header-container{ border-bottom: 20px solid #22558b; width:100% }
#footer-container{ border-top:    20px solid #22558b; width:100%}
#main aside      { border-top:    20px solid #22558b; }

#header-container,
#footer-container,
#main aside{
    background:#2c6cb1;
}

#title{color:white; }

::-moz-selection { background: #2c6cb1; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection      { background: #2c6cb1; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }

/* ==============
    MOBILE: Menu
   ============== */

nav a{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:15px 0;

    background:#22558b;
    color:white;

    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}

nav a:hover, nav a:visited{
    color:white;
}

nav a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

/* ==============
    MOBILE: Main
   ============== */

#main{
    padding:30px 0;
}

#main article h1{
    font-size:2em;
}

#main aside{
    color:white;
    padding:0px 5% 10px;
}

#footer-container footer{
    color:white;
    padding:20px 0;
    clear:both;
    }

/* ===============
    ALL: IE Fixes
   =============== */

.ie7 #title{ padding-top:20px; }

/* ===== Primary Styles ========================================================
   Author: Christopher Leah of Happy Webs LTD - 07/2012
   ========================================================================== */
 .btn{clear:left;float:left; width:79px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:2px;}
.ColHead{float:left; width:50px; margin-left:5px; background-color:#22558B;color:#ffffff;margin-bottom:2px;}
.RowHead{clear:left;float:left; width:75px; margin-left:5px;background-color:#2C6CB1;color:#ffffff;margin-bottom:2px;}
.gridBoxes{float:left; width:50px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:2px;}
.graph{margin-top:10px;float:left;}
h3.left {float: left; width:49%;}
h3.right {float: right; width:49%; text-align:right;}
#footer-container a { color:#fff; text-decoration:none; }
#footer-container a:hover { text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; }
.txtSmall {width:50px;}
#title a{color:#fff; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; text-decoration:none;}
.disclaimer { font-size:0.8em;}
.disclaimer a{ color:#22558B;}


/* =============================================================================
   Media Queries
   ========================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {

/* ====================
    INTERMEDIATE: Menu
   ==================== */  
    nav a{
        float:left;
        width:27%;
        margin:0 1.7%;
        padding:25px 2%;
        margin-bottom:0;
    }   
    nav li:first-child a{ margin-left:0;  }
    nav li:last-child  a{ margin-right:0; } 
/* ========================
    INTERMEDIATE: IE Fixes
   ======================== */

    nav ul li{
        display:inline;
    }   
    .oldie nav a{
        margin:0 0.7%;      
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

/* ====================
    WIDE: CSS3 Effects
   ==================== */

    #header-container,
    #main aside{
        -webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 10px #aaa;
           -moz-box-shadow:0 5px 10px #aaa;
                box-shadow:0 5px 10px #aaa;
    }

/* ============
    WIDE: Menu
   ============ */

    #title{
        float:left;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    }

    nav{
        float:right;
        width:38%;
    }

/* ============
    WIDE: Main
   ============ */

    #main article{
        float:left;
        width:57%;
    }

    #main aside{
        float:right;
        width:28%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1140px) {

/* ===============
    Maximal Width
   =============== */

    .wrapper{
        width:1026px; /* 1140px - 10% for margins */
        margin:0 auto;
    }
}

/* =============================================================================
   Non-Semantic Helper Classes
   ========================================================================== */

.ir { display: block; border: 0; text-indent: -999em; overflow: hidden; background-color: transparent; background-repeat: no-repeat; text-align: left; direction: ltr; *line-height: 0; }
.ir br { display: none; }
.hidden { display: none !important; visibility: hidden; }
.visuallyhidden { border: 0; clip: rect(0 0 0 0); height: 1px; margin: -1px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; position: absolute; width: 1px; }
.visuallyhidden.focusable:active, .visuallyhidden.focusable:focus { clip: auto; height: auto; margin: 0; overflow: visible; position: static; width: auto; }
.invisible { visibility: hidden; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }

/* =============================================================================
   Print Styles
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
  * { background: transparent !important; color: black !important; box-shadow:none !important; text-shadow: none !important; filter:none !important; -ms-filter: none !important; } /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
  a, a:visited { text-decoration: underline; }
  a[href]:after { content: " (" attr(href) ")"; }
  abbr[title]:after { content: " (" attr(title) ")"; }
  .ir a:after, a[href^="javascript:"]:after, a[href^="#"]:after { content: ""; }  /* Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links */
  pre, blockquote { border: 1px solid #999; page-break-inside: avoid; }
  thead { display: table-header-group; } /* h5bp.com/t */
  tr, img { page-break-inside: avoid; }
  img { max-width: 100% !important; }
  @page { margin: 0.5cm; }
  p, h2, h3 { orphans: 3; widows: 3; }
  h2, h3 { page-break-after: avoid; }
}
```

Heres my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->

<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head id="Head1"><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" /><title>

    Home - Upper Control Limit

</title><meta name="description" /><meta name="author" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

    <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>

    <div id="header-container">

        <header class="wrapper clearfix">

            <h1 id="title"><a href="default.aspx" title="Upper Control Limit Homepage">Upper Control Limit</a></h1>

            <nav>

                <ul>

                    <li><a href="default.aspx">Home</a></li>

                    <li><a href="contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>

            </nav>

        </header>

    </div>

    <div id="main-container">

            <form method="post" action="default.aspx" id="Form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="aspNetHidden">

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUIMzI4MjE1NjZkZO1bVtBx0KanNtHBuPKe20ZygwvsWgeEn3cRtL/CrOHU" />

</div>



<div class="aspNetHidden">



    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBQK3heD7DwLHyoqxBgLHyuK8AQKDw8wMAt3oqtEMt6vvVJr549pcOORe6AIL/bfdHDA/UvYWb5jzHlW8pc0=" />

</div>



    <div id="main" class="wrapper clearfix">

            <article>

                <section>

                    <h2>Manual Data Entry</h2>



                    <label>Rows:&nbsp;</label><input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtRows" type="text" id="MainContent_txtRows" class="txtSmall" />

                    <label>Cols:&nbsp;</label><input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtCols" type="text" id="MainContent_txtCols" class="txtSmall" />

                    <p><em>*Maximum of 10 rows and/or 30 columns for this trial version.</em></p>

                    <p><input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnGo" value="Go" id="MainContent_btnGo" /></p>

                    <br />

                 </section> 

                <section>

                    <h2>File Uploader</h2>



                    <p><input type="file" name="ctl00$MainContent$flUp" id="MainContent_flUp" />&nbsp;</p>

                    <p>(Maximum File Size: 3KB)<br /><em>*Do not include any column headers or text in your CSV.</em></p>

                    <p><input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnUpload" value="Upload" id="MainContent_btnUpload" /></p>

                    <br />

                </section>  

                <section>

                    <h3>Disclaimer</h3>

                    <p class="disclaimer">Data uploaded or manually entered, is deleted immediately 

                        after processing. If you have concerns over your data or privacy, please read our <a href="disclaimer.aspx" title="UCL Disclaimer">disclaimer</a>.<br />If your data contains sensitive information, you should consider 

                        integrating the UCL engine within your system.  Please <a href="contact.aspx" title="Contact us">contact us</a> for more information. <br /></p>

                </section>              

            </article>                          

            <aside>

                <h3>About UCL</h3>

                <p>Control Charts have multiple applications in a wide variety of industries. They 

                    can help measure the effectiveness of manufacturing processes or the quality of 

                    service based industry.</p>

                <p>The UCL calculator has been developed by Data-Exchange Ltd as a side project 

                which was driven by the need to integrate this magic formula within various 

                business applications.</p>

                <h4>Upper Control Limit Formula</h4>

                <p><img src="img/ucl-formula.png" title="Upper Control Limit Formula" alt="Upper Control Limit Formula: X + 2.66* MR" /></p>

                <h4>Lower Control Limit Formula</h4>

                <p><img src="img/lcl-formula.png" title="Lower Control Limit Formula" alt="Lower Control Limit Formula: X - 2.66* MR" /></p>

            </aside>

    </div>



            </form>

    </div> <!-- #main-container -->

    <div id="footer-container">

        <footer class="wrapper clearfix">

            <h3 class="left">Copyright © 2012 <a href="http://www.data-exchange.co.uk/" title="Data Exchange Ltd">Data Exchange Ltd</a></h3>

            <h3 class="right"><a href="http://www.perfect-flow.com/" title="PerfectFlow Ltd" ><img alt="PerfectFlow" border="0" src="img/perfectflow.gif" /></a></h3>

        </footer>

    </div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];

    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-17073042-4']);

    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function () {

        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;

        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

    })();

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: Too much information... tl;dr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your styles come after the CSS from Boilerplate, that should apply. It's the beauty of CASCADING stylesheets. Trying using `position:fixed` and `bottom:0px` for your footer.

```
#footer-container {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, I do have another question the footer now works great and does take up 100% of the screen when scrolling across, when big data amounts of fields are added linearly. But for some reason I can't get the header to follow suit, I kind of tried the direct opposite of the code you gave me for the footer, to try and make the header-container work 100% of browser but it doesn't seem to like that. Any ideas? Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 2):

Try doing something to this effect...

```
#footer-container {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, I do have another question the footer now works great and does take up 100% of the screen when scrolling across, when big data amounts of fields are added linearly. But for some reason I can't get the header to follow suit, I kind of tried the direct opposite of the code you gave me for the footer, to try and make the header-container work 100% of browser but it doesn't seem to like that. Any ideas? Thanks again guys!

Comment: By opposite affect you tried. position:fixed; top:0; on your ID of header-container is that correct? ... If not then that is what you should try, because that should work.

Comment: Ye I did that but then of course that messed up the rest of the page flow, but I want only the top and head to stay the same but somehow the rest of main container and aside to flow and bounce off the other boxes as if they weren't absolute or fixed.

Comment: HMM... you might have to restructure your markup a bit then. Because postion:fixed; top:0; should work. Check out twitter bootstrap for a good example of this... http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 2):

Take the BP, then add the additional markup stated on this page: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/html-code.html. Then, add the appropriate CSS. If you view it in tree mode via Firebug, it will help. After you getting working with the additional markup, see if you can repurpose your existing markup to clean things up a bit.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to what you wish me to do, I do know my code isn't incredibly clean.

Comment: You have two templates which need to work together. The BP, and the SF. Make each of them work independently, then merge. You should be able to get the SF to work by following the instructions on the SF site. Then, inject your BP code into the SF template. If you don't understand this, then you are probably in over your head. However, I think you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: I understand, I can do that (Y)

Answer (score 1):

The best way for having a sticky footer in an elegant way without any workaround you should use this css code:

```
#footer{
position:fixed;
clear:both;
}
```